# react error: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I m trying to render a list output from MAP. Whats it is I am coding wrong to get this error?

```
import React from 'react';


function Testmap2() {
    
const list = [
    {
        id: 'a',
        firstname: 'Robin',
        lastname: 'Wieruch',
        year: 1988,
    },
    {
        id: 'b',
        firstname: 'Dave',
        lastname: 'Davidds',
        year: 1990,
    },
];


 
    const testmapd = () => (
        <ul>
            {list.map(item => (
                <li key={item.id}>
                    <div>{item.id}</div>
                    <div>{item.firstname}</div>
                    <div>{item.lastname}</div>
                    <div>{item.year}</div>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            {testmapd}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Testmap2;
```

Error:
1.chunk.js:77900 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
in div (at Testmap2.jsx:37)
in Testmap2 (at src/index.js:13)
in StrictMode (at src/index.js:11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your function

```
<div>
   {testmapd()}
</div>
```

`const testmapd` is a variable that is referencing the arrow function you defined(ES6)

If you were to console.log testmapd, it would print the function body because that is what the variable is pointing to. When you add `()` after the function, it gets invoked/runs and returns something.

In your case, you didn't want the function definition, but the statement your function returns.

Comment: Thanks Hyetigran .. Appreciate your prompt response. testmapd is a result of the arrow function. How come testmapd() is a function and renders inside <div />

Comment: @nktoronto you're welcome! I added a bit more detail, hope it's helpful. Feel free to follow up if you're still unsure.

Comment: testmapd isn't result of arrow function. You have assigned arrow function to testmapd variable. Now to call the function, you need to write testmapd().

Answer (score 2):

Your `testmapd` is basically a React functional component. Treat it as such:

```js
const Testmapd = () => (
    <ul>
        {list.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
                <div>{item.id}</div>
                <div>{item.firstname}</div>
                <div>{item.lastname}</div>
                <div>{item.year}</div>
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
);

return (
    <div>
        <Testmapd />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks AryanJ .. Appreciate your prompt response. This answer is also correct and resolves the issue.  <Testmapd  /> does work. I did not know this way. I was trying to render const inside <div>testmapd</div>

Comment: @Aryan-J-NYC I like your answer!

Comment: Thanks. It _probably_ should be the accepted answer as it's more consistent with the way React is used.