# Returning all emails from a text in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return all the typed emails from the given textArea. But this is showing this error on the console.

**index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
at p
at div
at div
at ExtractEmail (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:763:81)
at div
at App**

This is my ExtractEmail Component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

function ExtractEmail(props) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    // const emailExtracted = useRef(null);
    

    const handleOnChange = (event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
        console.log(event.target.value);
    };

    const extractEmails = () => {
        return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/gi);
        }

    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <h1>Extract Emails</h1>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <textarea
                    name=""
                    id="myBox"
                    value={text}
                    onChange={handleOnChange}
                    cols="30"
                    rows="10"
                    className="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary my-3" onClick={extractEmails}>
                Extract Emails
            </button>
            <div className="mb-3">
            <p>Emails: {extractEmails}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        </>
        
    );
}

export default ExtractEmail;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react error: Functions are not valid as a React child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887513/react-error-functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is indicating that you are attempting to render a function. It is occurring on this line:

```
<p>Emails: {extractEmails}</p>
```

`extractEmails` is a function. It should instead be

```
<p>Emails: {extractEmails()}</p>
```